# Use CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, appear: OnDestroy or PostNcDestroy in derived class will not be called

Tags: mfc

The dialog box will pop up in static mode, as follows:

```
CTestDlg dlg;

dlg.DoModal ();
```

Ctestdlg contains cmfcpropertygridctrl control

When the ctestdlg dialog box pops up, you will see:

```
AppMsg - Warning: calling DestroyWindow in CWnd::~CWnd; OnDestroy or
PostNcDestroy in derived class will not be called.
```

If I remove the cmfcpropertygridctrl control, this warning will not appear.

But it has to be used, so what should we do to make the warning disappear?

Comment: You can find here some references regarding your issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn017-destroying-window-objects?view=msvc-160

Comment: Did you already try to put a breakpoint in `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnDestroy` of the `afxpropertygridctrl.cpp` file to see what happens? Mine is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxpropertygridctrl.cpp`

Comment: Not enough information. Show us, how do you create the mfcpropertygrid ctrl.